# select/unselect all elements in one go in primefaces <p:selectCheckboxMenu>?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have gone through the documentation of primefaces and sadly there is no option to select all the options of the `p:selectCheckboxMenu` component in one go like you can using Javascript.

Can anyone suggest how it can be done using Javascript or using the Backing Bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just preset its value with the same value as the available values the usual way (like as you would do for every other JSF input component).

Based on the [PrimeFaces showcase example of `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/checkboxMenu.xhtml), here's how it should look like:

```
package org.primefaces.examples.view;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FormBean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> selectedMovies;

    private Map<String,String> movies;

    public FormBean() {
        movies = new HashMap<String, String>();
        movies.put("Scarface", "Scarface");
        movies.put("Goodfellas", "Goodfellas");
        movies.put("Godfather", "Godfather");
        movies.put("Carlito's Way", "Carlito's Way");

        selectedMovies = new ArrayList<String>();
        selectedMovies.add("Scarface");
        selectedMovies.add("Goodfellas");
        selectedMovies.add("Godfather");
        selectedMovies.add("Carlito's Way");
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedMovies() {
        return selectedMovies;
    }
    public void setSelectedMovies(List<String> selectedMovies) {
        this.selectedMovies = selectedMovies;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }
}
```

Note that the `selectedMovies` is been prepared in bean's constructor. This can of course be done more elegantly based on the `Map movies`. It's just to give you the idea.

Doing this with JavaScript is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="someclass-selectall"/>choose all</label><br/>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="someclass"/>some text</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="someclass"/>some text</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="someclass"/>some text</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="someclass"/>some text</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="someclass"/>some text</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="someclass"/>some text</label><br/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../share/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 // use jquery
 $(".someclass-selectall").click(function  (  ) {
    $("input:checkbox.someclass").attr ( "checked", this.checked );
 })
</script>
```

try this